# cordova plugin, navigator.notification.alert throwing TypeError for Windows 10

Tags: javascript, windows-10, cordova-plugins, oracle-maf, apache-cordova

We are using `apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs`(that supports iOS, android and Windows platform) for displaying dialog(alert, confirm, prompt).

Tried calling the alert using `navigator.notification.alert` and `window.alert= navigator.notificationalert()`

But every time we are getting

```
JavaScript Callback navigator.notification.alert Threw Exception:TypeError: Unable to get property 'alert' of undefined or null reference error.
```

why is `notification` resolved to undefined?
The same plugin is working fine for Android and iOS

Note: Trying to show the alert after the device becomes ready

Comment: Having the same issue.
This used to work... not sure why its not now :(

Comment: @GavinPickin are you trying this in Mobile Application Frame Work?

Comment: Yes, inside a JqueryMobile application

Comment: Ok. seems like MAF issue in supporting cordova plugins. They are working on resolving the same.

Comment: Meanwhile we started using native alert